# NodeJS: Not able to access an image using ajax GET method.But the same URL loads the image in the browser without any issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, azure

When I try to access a image in Azure storage using ajax GET method I am getting the below error

```
Failed to load https://server/blobContainer/5a7389786136171dc06247cd: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But if I past the URL `https://server/blobContainer/5a7389786136171dc06247cd` in my browser the image loads in the browser without any issue. And I don't see 'Origin' in the request header. Only in Ajax call i see the 'Orgin' in the request header.

Please help me to access the image using ajax GET method

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the code that you are using for AJAX request. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls are subject to [Cross Origin Restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (commonly abbreviated CORS) which means you can't by default make an Ajax call to a different origin than the one the web page was loaded from.  An origin is defined by its protocol, host and port.

`<img>` tags do not have CORS restrictions.

To allow CORS requests, the server you are trying to make a CORS request of needs to specifically allow it.  You cannot fix this purely from the client.  A server allows a CORS request by including certain CORS-related headers and perhaps even (in some cases) by support a special OPTIONS request that is required for some types of CORS requests.

The error message you see: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` is the browser telling you that the target host did not specifically allow you to make a CORS request so the browser is blocking your ajax call.

> Please help me to access the image using ajax GET method

The target server will have to add the appropriate CORS headers to the response before the browser will let you contact it.  You can read a lot more about CORS [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Another way around CORS limitations is to use a proxy server that does support CORS.  You make a request to the proxy and tell it what URL you want it to fetch for you.  The proxy server (which is not subject to CORS limitations as this is a browser limitation only) then goes and gets the desired resource on your behalf and then returns it back from the proxy as the response to your original request to the proxy.

It sounds a bit unusual to be loading an image with an Ajax call.  You can load images with an `<img>` tag or you can create an image object in browser Javascript with `new Image()` and then you can load an image into that.  Neither of those are subject to CORS limitations.

Comment: @jfriend00-Thanks !